# Modification of Krushkal's algorithm in O(E) time

Tags: algorithm, graph, kruskals-algorithm

Suppose that the edges of G = (V,E) have weights in{1,2}. Modify Krushkal's  algorithm such that it runs in O(E) time.

I am new to the algorithm. what can be the logic of this?

Comment: You found the `kruskals-algorithm` tag: Why spell the name differently in title and question?

Answer (score 0):

Kruskal's algorithm is [basically the following](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm):

- create a forest F (a set of trees), where each vertex in the graph is a separate tree
- create a set S containing all the edges in the graph
- while S is nonempty and F is not yet spanning

  - remove an edge with minimum weight from S
  - if the removed edge connects two different trees then add it to the forest F, combining two trees into a single tree

Assuming you're using the [disjoing set data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure), the cost is dominated by maintaining the set *S*, allowing to initially hold all edges, then find the lightest of remaining edges. However, if all edges have weights 1 or 2, you can implement this with two linked lists, one per weight, and each operation will be *O(1)*.

Comment: 'you can implement this with two linked lists' How? Can you explain more.

Comment: 'and each operation will be O(1)' are you talking about the operations in disjoint set data structure?

Comment: @AyushMishra I was referring to the set/priority-queue operations. The disjoint-set data structure ops are considered de-facto O(1).

Comment: How do you check whether two elements belonging to the same set. And how do you merge two existing sets? Are they the same as in original algorithm using path compression, because it's not O(1).

Comment: @AyushMishra As I said before, that part is done using the standard disjoint set data structure. The original algorithm incidentally does not use only path compression, and the combination of the *two* heuristics (compression + union by rank) is indeed effectively considered O(1).

Comment: Okay. Earlier I misunderstood S for the disjoint-set datastructure, but it maintains the edges. And I was unaware that the complexity of disjoint set with compression + union by rank is prop. to inverse ackermann function ( i always thought it to be (log n) amortized).

Comment: @AyushMishra That's OK. And I think that the data structure with the two heuristics is one of the coolest things, esp. considering how simple it is.

Comment: So basically the complexity is reduced as we don't require sorting / heap for getting minimal edge consecutively. Storing edges with 1 and 2 weights separately in linear time and using edges with weight 1 followed by weight 2 will suffice.

Comment: @AyushMishra Exactly. All the best.

Comment: Agreed. Considering that without those heuristics the naive algorithm works in logarithmic per operation.

Comment: I disagree with your claim that inverse-Ackermann complexity is "effectively considered" O(1).  It has *never* been called that in anything I've read, including teaching materials -- it's always called "almost constant" or similar.  The OP's problem can be solved in genuine O(|E|) time by a simple algorithm (though admittedly, calling this algorithm a "modification of Kruskal" is a stretch, and massively confusing for anyone trying to figure out what it is).

Comment: @j_random_hacker The [Wikipedia Entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure#Disjoint-set_forests) clearly states this: "Since \alpha(n) is the inverse of this function, \alpha(n) is less than 5 for all remotely practical values of n. " IIRC, CLRS estimated this for the number of particles in the universe.

Comment: The Wikipedia article does make that point, but (like every source I know of) stops short of saying that the time complexity of those operations *is* O(1).  In my answer I give an algorithm that is actually O(|E|) (but which doesn't look too much like Kruskal, admittedly).

Answer (score -1):

**[EDIT: This algorithm produces a minimum spanning *forest* of G, a la Kruskal.  This forest will be a tree iff G is connected.]**

[Ami Tavory's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36292263/47984) would be fine in practice, and the inverse-Ackermann complexity of the disjoint-set operations it uses behave like O(1) on any problem that could be described in our physical universe, but they aren't truly O(1), so the overall algorithm isn't truly O(|E|).

Nevertheless, if the input is given as an edge list, or if the fraction (or total number) of vertices that are isolated vertices is bounded by some constant, then there *is* an O(|E|) algorithm, and it's actually pretty simple -- although calling it a "modification of Kruskal" is a huge stretch, and very confusing for someone trying to figure out what it is.  (Note that if my assumption here doesn't hold -- that is, if the input is not given as an edge list, and there is no bound on the fraction of isolated vertices -- then in the worst case no algorithm can even *look at all the input data* in O(|E|) time: G could have no edges at all, and billions of isolated vertices.)

### The algorithm

The basic idea is to repeatedly use DFS to find connected components using only edges having the smallest weight that hasn't been considered yet, and then collapse these components into single vertices.  The algorithm works in O(k(|E|+|V|)) time, where k is the number of distinct edge weights in the input graph -- so whenever the above assumption about the input holds and k is bounded by a constant (here k <= 2), the resulting algorithm is O(|E|).  I assume here that the input is given as an edge list E, but if the input is in adjacency-list form it can be converted to this form in O(|E|) time.

1. Find the smallest edge weight x.  (If the set of distinct edge weights is not given as part of the problem, this can be done in O(|E|) time, just by looking at each edge.)
2. Create an adjacency-list representation of the subgraph G_x that consists of just the edges having weight x and the vertices they connect.  This takes O(|E|) time.
3. Create an array c[] of |V(G)| values, and set c[v] = v for all 1 <= v <= |V(G)|.  For vertices in G_x, c[v] will come to hold the "label" for vertex v, which will be the smallest-numbered vertex in the connected component of G_x that contains v.  For vertices v not in V(G_x), it will be convenient later to set c[v] = v now anyway.
4. Loop through all vertices in G_x in increasing order.  For any as-yet unvisited vertex v (that is, for any v having c[v] = v), start a depth-first search at this vertex that

   1. sets c[u] = v for every vertex u visited during the DFS, and
   2. appends each taken edge to a list T (note that T is preserved across iterations).

   It takes O(|E_x|+|V_x|) = O(|E_x|) = O(|E|) time to perform all of these DFSes, because no edge or vertex of G_x is visited by more than one DFS.  Also note that the test "c[v] = v?" can be used to check whether a vertex v has already been visited, without the need for a separate "seen[]" array as is sometimes needed for DFS.
5. Create an empty list E'.  For each edge uv in the original graph G:

   1. If w(uv) = x, do nothing.  (These edges will be discarded.)
   2. Otherwise, append the edge (c[u], c[v]) with weight w(uv) to E'.

   This step creates the edges E' of a new graph G' = (V, E') in which each connected component in G_x has been effectively shrunk to a single vertex (namely, the smallest-numbered vertex in the component), and all other edges are left unchanged.  Note that E' can contain duplicate edges, but this does not affect correctness (DFS handles them just fine) or hurt the time complexity (since clearly |E'| <= |E|).
6. If |E'| > 0, set E = E' and start again from step 1 (or equivalently, recurse to solve E' and append the resulting edge list to T).
7. When we get to this point, T is a minimum spanning <strike>tree</strike>forest for G.

Each step takes at most O(|E|) time, and the whole algorithm runs at most k times, so the overall algorithm is O(|E|) under the assumptions given at the outset.  There are a few practical speedups that could be implemented, like using bucket sort to sort the edges by weight initially, and (again by bucket sorting) removing the duplicate edges generated in step 5.

Comment: I think this answer has two problems: 1. As you noted, it's actually confusing to view this as a modification of Kruskal - which is what the question asks for. 2. According to your own strict criteria by which inverse Ackermann is not O(1), it does not satisfy your stated complexity at all. Many of the steps contain pointer or arithmetic operations that are very slowly growing, but not strictly constant.

Comment: Sorry, but you're mistaken. The unit-cost RAM model wasn't conceived by theoreticians guessing that it would be interesting to invent a model where pointer and arithmetic ops. are *deemed* O(1). It is simply a reflection that for realistic sizes, these are effectively constant, so it's uninteresting to tally the cost by the log of the input size(s). By this rationale, inverse Ackerman is of course effectively constant as well, because it grows slower. Conversely, under any model where inverse Ackerman is not constant, then your answer is not constant as well.

Comment: @AmiTavory: I apologise for the snark (which someone has since had deleted, along with my other snark-free comments), but nevertheless it's you who is mistaken here.  To claim that pointer and arithmetic operations are O(1), I need only assume the unit-cost RAM model, which (like all models) is unrealistic in some ways.  You can challenge the applicability/relevance of this model to real computers, but not my complexity claim. ...

Comment: @AmiTavory: ...  By comparison, for you to claim that O(invAck) = O(1) is a much stronger claim: that O(invAck) != O(1) is a mathematical truth that does not depend on the choice of any particular computational model, and for you to deny it requires that you abandon the Big-Oh framework altogether.  I encourage you to ask a respected colleague with CS training about this distinction, if you remain unconvinced.